# How to enable Azure MultiFactor Athentication for a Microsoft (Personal) account that is the Administrator Account

Tags: azure

How can I enable MultiFactor Authentication for my "Personal" Microsoft account, from within my azure Subscription?

The Microsoft account is the Creator / Administrator of the Azure AD, and I have a subscription setup.

Yet when trying to enable MFA, there is a note saying that only Administrators "Homed" in this AD can be activated for MFA..

Why can't I create MFA for the Microsoft account, which is the Administrator of the entire Azure AD?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For live accounts, visit [this link](https://account.live.com/proofs/Manage) and log in.  Once in there, navigate to teh Security & Password tab and you should be able to enable 2FA for your live id.